# Cronjob execution based on different timezone (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, timezone

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Cron: cron/bionic,now 3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1 amd64

System timezone is: America/Los_Angeles (PST)

---

I want to set timezone of an EXECUTION TIME (not the timezone for the script) for specific job to America/New_York (EST).

Example: I want the script to execute at 3pm (EST-New_York) which is 12pm (PST-Los_Angeles, local system time)

Tried, with no success:

```
0 15 * * * CRON_TZ=America/New_York /script/path/here

0 15 * * * CRON_TZ="America/New_York" /script/path/here

0 15 * * * TZ=America/New_York /script/path/here

0 15 * * * TZ="America/New_York" /script/path/here

0 15 * * * CRON_TZ=America/New_York /script/path/here

CRON_TZ="America/New_York"
0 15 * * * /script/path/here

CRON_TZ=America/New_York
0 15 * * * /script/path/here

TZ="America/New_York"
0 15 * * * /script/path/here

TZ=America/New_York
0 15 * * * /script/path/here
```

Is there a solution to this at all?

Comment: Why not `0 0 * * *`? (Or perhaps `0 12 * * *`-- depends on what 12pm is supposed to mean - strictly speaking there is only `noon` and `midnight` at 12 sharp)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I want to set time according to EST while the local system is PST.